# ElasticSearch Wildcard Tokenizer for Emails

Tags: email, elasticsearch, token, analyzer

Suppose there are five email addresses stored under field "email":

```
1. {"email": "john_1@gmail.com"}
2. {"email": "john_2@gmail.com"}
3. {"email": "john_3@outlook.com"}
4. {"email": "john_4@outlook.com}
5. {"email": "john_5@yahoo.com"}
```

When I try to search with full email address I get the proper result. Where as If I try to search with partial email I gives me no result.

For example If I try to search only `joh` or `john_`. However if I try to search john_1 I am able to get the result. How to get the wildcard result in this case.

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "email": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original": 1,
          "patterns": [
            "([^@]+)",
            "(\\p{L}+)",
            "(\\d+)",
            "@(.+)",
            "([^-@]+)"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "email": {
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": [
            "email",
            "lowercase",
            "unique"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "emails": {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "email",
          "search_analyzer": "standard",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Wildcard Query.

Example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "email": {
        "value": "joh*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when using wildcard searching for full email id gives me zero result.

Comment: what version ES? I get results with your samples.

Comment: I think special characters are causing some issue. When I search for 'john_1' or 'gmail.com' but when I search it by whole keyword like john_1@gmail.com it gives me no result any suggestion for that.